# How to recover the System after rm -r / -command string

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

I'm willing to learn how to recover the System after system administrator (root user) have hit "rm -r /" -command string by accident after learning some new nice commands. My customer is humanist approached and he got a old computer with native Mint -distro but he doesn't know nothing about terminal UNIX commands. He is using only Desktop-GUI-environment.

I gave him lesson about some basic Linux -commands but did not warned about using this recursive remove-command including all the subdirectories. If he call me and tell me that he tried this rm -r / I have to fix the system. Never done it before. Please help.

Comment: Is there anything important on the computer? If so, concentrate on saving that first -- if the important files are still there, copy them someplace safe; if not, look into deleted file recovery tools and *don't change any files on the system (including those done simply by running the OS) until you're done with the recovery process*. Then you're probably going to have to reinstall from scratch. And: this is a good lesson in why you should always have backups.

Comment: BTW, to clarify my warning about making changes: when a file gets deleted (e.g. by `rm`), the space its contents are stored in becomes available to store new/changed files. Until that space gets reused, the file's contents are potentially recoverable (with the right tools. Once that space gets reused, it's not even potentially recoverable. Hence, to maximize the chances of recovery, you should avoid adding/changing any files on that disk.

Comment: ^^^ Gordon is right. One more detail: you may be able to recover deleted files but probably not the deleted directory structure, permissions etc. Therefore fixing the system without reinstalling from scratch is rarely possible. Even If the customer interrupted `rm` soon enough, so there are only *few* things missing in the OS itself, nowadays it's easier to reinstall anyway. Compare [*THE* classic Unix horror story](https://hackerfall.com/story/the-classic-unix-horror-story) by Mario Wolczko. It won't help you but it's magnificent.

Comment: Thanks for help!I got some studies at Educational Sciences after my Matriculation Exam so I would have to know some basic thinking down there at the pedagogical way to approach the teaching things. My friend got words used to say, "Motto", as we say it in Finnish language": All the things got at least two sides or even more" so he asked me for the opposite of cp -R /$HOME/Desktop for the copying all importat files he is lying on his Desktop. I was forced to tell him rm -r -for recursice removal -command even if I know the catastrofical results of the recursive use for the root directory use.